# match exact number in string (and no partial match inside bigger numbers)

Tags: php, regex

I want to match an exact number inside a string. For example i search for `"123"` and want to match it in `"123", "asdf123x", "99 123"` but not if it is only a partial match in a "bigger" number. So it won't match `"0123", "1234", "123123"`.

Because of "asdf123x" i can not use word boundaries.
I have tried to start with a negative lookahead like this (and planned to add a negative look behind, but even the lookahead on its own does not work as i thought it would:

```
$string = "123"; //or one of the other examples   
preg_match('/(?!\d)123/',$string,$matches);
```

This never matches and i dont get why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
'/(?<!\d)123(?!\d)/'
  ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK2qP8/1).

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` will fail the match if there is a digit before `123` and the negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a digit after `123`.

See more about [*negative lookarounds* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/elMItn):

```
$string = "123"; //or one of the other examples   
if (preg_match("/(?<!\d)$string(?!\d)/", "123123",$matches)) {
    echo "Matched!";
} else {
    echo "Not matched!";
}
```

Comment: Omg i missinterpreted the words "lookbehind" and "lookahead", therefore i tried '/(?!\d)123(?<!\d)/' instead of  '/(?<!\d)123(?!\d)/' - thanks!

Comment: Actually, `(?!\d)123` will never match since `(?!\d)` requires the next char to be anything but a digit.

Comment: Yes the point was that i used a lookahead "ahead" of the pattern that i wanted to match - missinterpretation of the meaning of "lookeahead"